# How to test dialogflow application in console when backend uses promises?

Tags: aws-lambda, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

The backend for my dialogflow application uses the actions-on-google sdk. And it makes request to another server. So, I had to return promises. It works perfect with the google assistant, but the dialog console can't handle it. The aws-sam-cli can't do it either (my backend is an aws lambda function).

--> How can I achieve that I can test my function locally and in the dialogflow console without destroying it for the google assistant?

Example:

```
return myAsyncTask(conv).then(() => {
    conv.ask(new SimpleResponse('Hello World');
});
```

In the dialogflow console, the response field contains "not available".
The response is this:

```
{
  "payload": {
    "google": {
      "expectUserResponse": true,
      "richResponse": {
        "items": [
          {
            "simpleResponse": {
              "textToSpeech": "MyText",
              "displayText": "MyDisplayText"
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "userStorage": "{\"data\":{}}"
    }
  },
  "outputContexts": [
    ...
  ]
}
```

The fulfillment field isn't filled. That could be an error, too. But I don't know how to fill it.

In the aws-cli I get this error:

> (node:1) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection
>   (rejection id: 1): TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to
>   object

and the response is null.

Comment: Can you give an example of what is happening when you test it with the Dialogflow test console or the AWS CLI?

Comment: @Prisoner: Sure! I added it to my question.

Answer (score 0):

First of all - it shouldn't matter if you're using a Promise or not. In fact, you *should* be using them, so you're a step ahead there.

Since it works with the Actions on Google simulator, that means that your code *can* send back results that are valid and make sense.

Part of the issue is that what you're sending back is specific for the Google Assistant - not for the Dialogflow tester. So it isn't surprising that you're sending back Assistant-specific content, but nothing that the generic Dialogflow test tool can handle. This likely means you're using the actions-on-google node.js library, and isn't a problem.

The error with aws-cli suggests more that you're not sending a valid request as part of your testing, so your code (or, more likely, the actions-on-google library) are tripping up over the poorly formatted input. To debug this, check the aws-lambda logs to see what errors are being caused, and possibly log the request that you're getting in the function as well.